# Div overlapping

Tags: css, html, positioning, z-index

I am trying to create two `<div>`'s that overlap. The only problem is that the second `<div>` is in front of the first `<div>` and it has to be the other way around.  I've tried setting the z-index of the first `<div>` to `1` but it still does not work.

Here is my code:

```
 #content{
background-color:pink;  
overflow:auto;
position:relative;

}
#content_1{

width:400px;
height:1600px;
background-color:#000099;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
}
nav{

width:300px;
height:500px;
background-color:yellow;


position:absolute;
top:0;  
right:200px;
z-index:0;

}
```

---

```
<div id="container">

  <header> </header>

   <div id="content">
       <div id="content_1"></div>
       <nav></nav>
 </div>

  <footer></footer>
 </div>
```

How can I make the first div overlap the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-indexing works when both elements share the same stacking context, both are positioned (relative or absolute), and both have a z-index attribute applied. In this case you've only applied the positioning and z indexing attributes to one.

Comment: <div id="container">
   
  <header> </header>
  
   <div id="content">
       <div id="content_1"></div>
       <nav></nav>
 </div>
 
  <footer></footer>
 </div>

Comment: thnak you it worked forgot to add positioning to the first div

Answer (score 1):

add position absolute to `content_1` or add position relative